# Plot 3D Shape in Maple

Tags: 3d, plot, maple

I'm trying to plot a 3D shape in Maple using the following 4 points: 
    [3, -5,-4],
    [4, -1, 3],
    [-4,-5, 4],
    [2, -5, 4]
    I have no idea what code to use or even where to begin.
    Any help would be very much appreciated
    Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you want, but here is how to draw a tetrahedron:

```
with(plots); # to get display
with(plottools); # to get polygon
v := [[3, -5,-4], [4, -1, 3], [-4,-5, 4], [2, -5, 4]];
combos:= combinat:-choose(v,3);
display(map(polygon,combos));
```

Comment: combos:= combinat:-choose(v,3);